# Falcor - 'get' no longer emits references as leaf values

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

I've recently upgraded from Falcor 0.x to 1.1.0 (2.x will be the next step)

According to the [Falcor migration documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/blob/1.0.0/MIGRATIONS.md#refs-no-longer-emitted-as-json), when calling `model.get` references are not emitted as json anymore.

I'm however wondering what would be the best practice in order to manage references in a `model.get`.

Here is an example.

Having the following json graph:

```
{
    jsonGraph: {
        comment: {
            123: {
                owner: { $type: "ref", value: ["user", "abc"] },
                message: "Foo"
            }
        },
        user: {
            abc: {
                name: "John Doe"
                initials: "JD"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `model.get` will result to:

```js
const json = await model.get(["comment", "123", ["owner", "message"]);

{
    owner: undefined, // 0.x was returning `["user", "abc"]`
    message: "John Doe"
}
```

However it's possible to get the owner only:

```js
const json = await model.get(["comment", "123", "owner", ["name", "initials"]);

{
    name: "John Doe",
    initials: "JD"
}
```

What is the recommendation for handling references in `model.get`?

Should I manually get the owner (like the last example?) or should I have an `ownerId` instead of an `owner` reference in `comment` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.get` can take any number of `pathSets` ([docs](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/Model.html#get)).  So, break your first `pathSet` into two and pass as separate arguments:

```
await model.get(
  ["comment", "123", "message"],
  ["comment", "123", "owner", ["name", "initials"]]
);
```

which should return

```
{
  message: "John Doe"
  owner: {
    name: "John Doe",
    initials: "JD"
  }
}
```

The underlying constraint is that a single pathSet can only include multiple paths of the same depth.  So multiple paths of different depth can only be represented by multiple pathSets.

Comment: Thank you ! I had a more complex use case with a list of comments (range), but after some tweaks that did the trick