# Falcor - Deep nested references not cached

Tags: falcor

I'm seeing an problem in Falcor client when I request a route that contain nested references.

Here is an example:

Consider the following JsonGraph response from Falcor server on a `model.get` call

```
{
  "todos": {
    "0": { "$type": "ref", "value": ["todosById", "id_0"] },
    "1": { "$type": "ref", "value": ["todosById", "id_1"] },
    "length": 2
  },
  "todosById": {
    "id_0": {
      "name": "get milk",
      "label": { "$type": "ref", "value": ["labelsById", "lbl_0"] },
      "completed": false
    },
    "id_1": {
      "name": "do the laundry",
      "label": { "$type": "ref", "value": ["labelsById", "lbl_1"] },
      "completed": false
    }
  },
  "labelsById": {
    "lbl_0": { "name": "groceries" },
    "lbl_1": { "name": "home" }
  }
}
```

When I call `model.get` with the following path, all the above jsonGraph result should be in cache:

```
model.get(['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, ['completed', 'label', 'name']])
```

However, manually accessing the cache, I can see `todos` and `todosById` are in cache, but not `labelsById`.

I'm not certain but it looks like `labelsById` is not in cache because it's a second level reference?

Am I missing something here or is that an expected behaviour of Falcor cache? 
Would there be any way to force `labelsById` to be in cache, so no additional datasource request would be made?

Any help is appreciated !

The problem can be reproduced in this small project:
https://github.com/ardeois/falcor-nested-references-cache-issue

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @james-conkling answer the json graph can be cached by doing the following `model.get`:

```
model.get(
  ['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, ['completed', 'name']],
  ['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, 'label', 'name']
);
```

However, on the server side Falcor Router will call `todos[{integers:indices}]` route twice. This could have an impact on API or database calls to whatever your Falcor server is fronting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pathset `['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, ['completed', 'label', 'name']]`, the paths ending with the `completed` and `name` keys terminates at an atom.  But the path ending with the `label` key terminates at a ref.  If you want to actually follow that ref, you'll have to include it as a second path:

```
[
   ['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, ['completed', 'name']],
   ['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, 'label', 'name']
]
```

In general, all paths should terminate on an atom, never on a ref.  I'm not sure what the expected behavior is for paths that terminate on a ref, or even if it's well defined (as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101216/falcor-get-no-longer-emits-references-as-leaf-values) notes, the behavior has changed from v0 to v1).

The `model.get(...paths)` call can take multiple pathSet arrays, so rewriting the query should be as straightforward as

```
model.get(
  ['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, ['completed', 'name']],
  ['todos', {from: 0, to: 1}, 'label', 'name']
);
```

---

## EDIT

As noted in the comments below, because the router handlers can only resolve a single pathSet at a time, GET requests with multiple pathSets can result in multiple requests to your upstream backing service/db.  Some possible solutions:

#### use a single path

Rewrite the request using a single path `['todos', range, ['completed', 'name', 'label'], 'name']`.  Technically, this request is asking for `todos.n.completed.name` and `todos.n.label.name` (which don't exist), in addition to `todos.n.label.name` (which does exist).

However, if your router handler returns pathValues for paths that are shorter than the matched path, the shorter pathValues should be merged into your jsonGraph cache. E.g. when matching `todos.0.completed.name`, return `{ path: ['todos', 0, 'completed'], value: true }`, while when matching `todos.0.label.name` return `{ path: ['todos', 0, 'label', 'name'], value: 'First TODO' }`.

This is probably the easiest approach, but means your queries aren't really semantically correct (you're knowingly asking for paths that don't exist).

#### batch upstream requests made by the router

In your router, batch upstream requests to your backing service/db.  This is not always straightforward.  One possible approach is to use facebook's [data-loader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader), written to solve an equivalent problem w/ GraphQL routers, but not necessarily tied to GraphQL.  Another approach could use a custom reducer function to combine requests issued w/i the same tick (e.g. [here](https://github.com/junonetwork/juno-falcor-router/blob/master/src/adapters/adapter.ts)).

#### rewrite your schema

So that all paths that need to be requested at the same time are of the same length.  This won't always be possible, though, so :shrug.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! However, doing 2 paths sets in the same `model.get` actually does 1 call to falcor server but the route will be resolved twice right ? One for accessing `completed` and `name` properties, one for accessing `label.name`. So this can generate (in Falcor server) 2 calls to the same endpoint or database.

Comment: @CorentinArdeois yes, using two paths means that your router handlers will get called twice, likely leading to two calls to the upstream backing service/db.  There are ways to handle this, but in general I see this as one of the biggest issues w/ Falcor.  I'll update my answer to explain ways to mitigate this.